# Disable double-bar separators in Lilypond

Tags: lilypond

I am exporting voices from a score I wrote in Lilypond. In the voices there are these double bars, which separate the lines from each other. How can I disable these double-bars?

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to disable them always, or only when exporting individual parts?

Comment: only for the parts, I found `system-separator-markup = ##f`, looks like what I am looking for